# Using Androidx test dependencies in Robolectric instrumentation tests

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric

I am having an issue with `testImplementation` and `androidTestImplementation`in build.gradle. I know that the former is used for unit tests while the latter for instrumentation tests.

Now, the problem is that Roboletric recommends using AndroidX `ActivityScenario` for launching activities and this class lives in `androidx.test:rules`. So to make `ActivityScenario` visible for unit tests, I will have to use `testImplementation` to declare `androidx.test:rules` dependency in build.gradle (e.g `testImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.1.1'`).

What this implies is that `androidx.test:rules` classes won't be available for instrumentation tests.

Please, how do I resolve this issue? Do I have to declare a separate `androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.1.1'` for instrumentaion tests while keeping `testImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.1.1'` for unit tests?

Comment: you might be mixing up instrumentation tests with unit tests; see this [blog post](https://medium.com/@ali.muzaffar/the-basics-of-unit-and-instrumentation-testing-on-android-7f3790e77bd). (the name-space of the package does not really matter there). besides, `com.android.support.test` obviously isn't [androidx.test](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/set-up-project).

Comment: I'm getting `ActivityScenario` from the `androidx.test:core` artifact, and yes use both `testImplementation` and `androidTestImplementation` if you want to use it for both.